# Realm Object Server Data Adapter with Docker Compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, realm, realm-object-server

I’m trying to configure an ecosystem with RealmObjectServer + Postgresql + DataAdapter using Docker Compose, but I can’t connect the Data Adapter server with the ROS because the adapter requires the HTTPS protocol. It keeps showing this error on my ros-adapter container:

```
ros-adapter_1  | Error: only http(s) protocols are supported
ros-adapter_1  |     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/node-fetch/index.js:58:10
ros-adapter_1  |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
ros-adapter_1  |     at new Fetch (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-fetch/index.js:49:9)
ros-adapter_1  |     at Fetch (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-fetch/index.js:37:10)
ros-adapter_1  |     at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/realm/lib/user-methods.js:57:9)
ros-adapter_1  |     at Promise (/usr/src/app/node_modules/realm/lib/user-methods.js:72:13)
ros-adapter_1  |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
ros-adapter_1  |     at performFetch (/usr/src/app/node_modules/realm/lib/user-methods.js:70:16)
ros-adapter_1  |     at refreshAdminToken (/usr/src/app/node_modules/realm/lib/user-methods.js:129:5)
ros-adapter_1  |     at refreshAccessToken (/usr/src/app/node_modules/realm/lib/user-methods.js:169:16)
```

Does anyone know how I can configure this properly in Realm.Adapter?

You can see the source code here: https://github.com/artutra/ros-adapter

Comment: I think you need to disable https for now in https://github.com/artutra/ros-adapter/blob/master/ros/src/index.ts#L52. We are working on getting better https/realms support in the adapter.

Comment: @geisshirt I disabled but the ros-adapater container is still trying to login with https in this line: https://github.com/artutra/ros-adapter/blob/master/ros-adapter/src/index.js#L28

Comment: @geisshirt Correction: the authentication works fine, but even with `https: false` it still showing the error.